# Net::Telnet question about authentication using -a option

Tags: perl, telnet

I had a perfectly working script using Perl Net::Telnet that connects via telnet to our application and executes commands.  Recently, a new "feature" was added to the application in which the user must connect with "telnet -a ..".  This -a option is for automatic login, and it sends the value of the env variable "User" to the application.  This way, our application can log the username of the user that executed the telnet commands.

This -a requirement broke my script, and I cannot see any way to use Net::Telnet with this requirement.  I have looked at the documentation and the source code. Anyone can help with this?

```
my $t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 3, Host => $host, Port => $port, Prompt => $prompt, Output_log => $log);
$t->cmd($cmd);
```

How can I use something like the above, but authenticate against the application I am connecting to?

Comment: To clarify your question, could you include a minimal script that illustrates the problem? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: It *might* be possible via the `option_accept` and `option_callback` methods

Comment: To clarify:  to connect to our application on the command line, I can do:
telnet -l dk localhost 61002
or
telnet -a localhost 61002
When I connect exactly like the code snippet in the original question, our application rejects the connection attempt because there is no USER passed to the application.
I am simply trying to understand how to overcome this issue, while continuing to use Net::Telnet.